# How to split TabbedPage ContentPage into different file

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I would like to follow SIP (Single Responsibility Principle).
I created the below `TabbedPage` with 3 tabs/Pages respectively (Page1, Page2 and Page3) and it works well.

I'm thinking of spliting each `ContentPage` onto its own xaml file so that each of its C# file (xaml.cs) file also can handle it's own `ContentPage`, but at the end they need to behave as a normal tabbedview page of 3 pages.

I'm looking at doing so as each `ContentPage` has to have many things (code) in it at the end of the day, that's why I'm thinking of separating each `ContentPage` into a single file from the beginning.

**Not sure if it's doable in Xamarin.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedPageApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">
    
    <!--android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Black"
             android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Red">-->
    
    <ContentPage Title="Page 1" IconImageSource="outline_settings_black_24dp.png">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin - TabbedPage 1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Yellow" FontSize="36"/>

                <Entry x:Name="entryB" />
                
                <Button x:Name="myButtonCancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
    
    
    <ContentPage Title="Page 2" IconImageSource="outline_add_shopping_cart_black_24dp.png">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin - TabbedPage 2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Yellow" FontSize="36"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
    
    
    <ContentPage Title="Page 3" IconImageSource="outline_account_circle_black_24dp.png">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin - TabbedPage 3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Yellow" FontSize="36"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#populate-a-tabbedpage-with-a-page-collection) explicitly show how to do this.  You just have to declare the namespace that your `ContentPage` XAML files are in

`PageOne`, etc are just `ContentPage` XAML files that you create in your project

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage"
            x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage">
    <local:PageOne />
    <local:PageTwo />
</TabbedPage>
```